# asp:Parameter not binding values properly

Tags: asp.net

My delete command isn't deleting.  When I click the delete button, I see the Get and Post events fire, but no changes are reflected in my database, or on the page.  If I assign a default value to the `asp:Parameter` the default value gets passed every time, and if it happens to exist in the database, the delete command evaluates properly and deletes the record.

```
<asp:SqlDataSource
    ID="AcknowledgementDataSource" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ProductionDatabaseConnectionString1 %>" 
    SelectCommand="select tblHRM_Acknowledgements.AcknowledgementID, tblHRM_Acknowledgements.Acknowledger, lstduperoncontacts.Contact as Acknowledgee, tblHRM_Acknowledgements.Comment from tblHRM_Acknowledgements left join lstduperoncontacts on tblHRM_Acknowledgements.acknowledgee = lstDuperonContacts.contactid where Acknowledger in (select lstDuperonContacts.ContactID from lstDuperonContacts where lstDuperonContacts.email = @lblemail)"
    InsertCommand="insert into tblHRM_Acknowledgements(Acknowledger, Acknowledgee, Comment) Select contactID, @ddlAck, @txtComment from lstDuperonContacts where email = @lblemail"         
    DeleteCommand="delete from tblHRM_Acknowledgements where tblHRM_Acknowledgements.AcknowledgementID = @AcknowledgementID">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="lblemail" Name="lblemail" />
        </SelectParameters>
        <InsertParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="lblemail" Name="lblemail" />
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlId="ddlAcknowledgee" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Name="ddlAck" />
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="txtComment" Name="txtComment" />
        </InsertParameters>
        <DeleteParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="AcknowledgementID" />
        </DeleteParameters>

    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

I feel like this is an obvious issue like a typo or something and I just can't find it, but I can't say for sure.  Anything jump out as wrong?

Listview that displays/deletes data:

```
    <asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="AcknowledgementDataSource">
        <AlternatingItemTemplate>
            <li style="">
                <asp:HiddenField ID="AcknowledgementField" Value='<%# Eval("AcknowledgementID") %>' runat="server" />
                Acknowledgee:
                <asp:Label ID="AcknowledgeeLabel" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# Eval("Acknowledgee") %>' />
                <br />
                Comment:
                <asp:Label ID="CommentLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Comment") %>' />
                <br />
                <asp:Button ID="DeleteButton" runat="server" CommandName="Delete" 
                    Text="Delete" />
            </li>
        </AlternatingItemTemplate>
        <EmptyDataTemplate>
            No data was returned.
        </EmptyDataTemplate>
        <ItemSeparatorTemplate>
            <br />
        </ItemSeparatorTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <li style="">
                <asp:HiddenField ID="AcknowledgementField" Value='<%# Eval("AcknowledgementID") %>' runat="server" />
                Acknowledgee:
                <asp:Label ID="AcknowledgeeLabel" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# Eval("Acknowledgee") %>' />
                <br />
                Comment:
                <asp:Label ID="CommentLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Comment") %>' />
                <br />
                <asp:Button ID="DeleteButton" runat="server" CommandName="Delete" 
                    Text="Delete" />
            </li>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <LayoutTemplate>
            <ul ID="itemPlaceholderContainer" runat="server" style="">
                <li runat="server" id="itemPlaceholder" />
            </ul>
            <div style="">
            </div>
        </LayoutTemplate>
    </asp:ListView>
```

Comment: How are you setting the value for the parameter?

Comment: Binds via `<asp:Label ID="AcknowledgementIDLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("AcknowledgementID") %>' style="display:none" />` in the `<ItemTemplate>` of a `<ListView>` that uses this datasource.

Comment: Can you show listview html code?

Comment: Put it up.  Has them as HiddenField's as per [Yuriy's](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12941909/312777) answer, still not deleting properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" DataKeyNames="AcknowledgementID".......
```

Use `DataKeyNames` property for listview.

[ListView.DataKeyNames Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview.datakeynames.aspx)